# Exercise 1-8. Write a program to count blanks, tabs, and newlines

Tags: c, count, tabs, getchar, blank-line

it's the K and R c programming exercise, I don't know why my program doesnt work, could anyone help, please and thank you.

When I run the program and type a line of words or two and hit 'Enter', it doesnt show anything, it just jumps to the next line and thats it

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
     int c, line, tab, blank;
    
    line = 0;
    tab = 0;
    blank = 0;
    
    while ( (c = getchar()) != EOF)
    {
        if (c == '\n')
            ++line; 

        if (c == '\t')
            ++tab;

        if (c == ' ')
            ++blank;
       
    }
    
    printf("Lines: %d\n Tabs: %d\n Blanks: %d\n", line, tab, blank);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: And please describe the problem better than "doesn't work". Give the exact input, expected result and actual result.

Comment: What doesn't work? Wrong counts, does not end, crashes, what? I compiled and ran it, no problem.

Comment: OT: your formatting of the `if` clauses is most strange and very unreadable.

Comment: @kaylum yes you're right, sorry for not being clear, basically when I run the program and type a line of words or two and hit 'Enter', it doesnt show anything, it just jumps to the next line and thats it

Comment: You need to type the `EOF` that the program is looking for: Ctrl-D on Linux, Ctrl-Z on Windows. Or direct a file to the input.

Comment: FYI, I have edited your code to show you the standard way that code blocks are indented. Each child block should be indented relative to the parent. And I haven't shown it but best practice is also to enclose even single line `if` bodies with `{ }`

Comment: @WeatherVane could you please explain more

Comment: Well if you run the program like `program < textfile.txt` then the contents of that text file are input to `stdin` instead of from the keyboard. At the end of the file, the program receives `EOF` even though there isn't an actual character like that in the file. Otherwise you have to type it. Windows is fussy though. The Ctrl-Z must be directly after a `Enter` is typed and then another `Enter` must be typed.

Comment: @WeatherVane thank you very much, now I see why it shows nothing.

Comment: @Jabberwocky Ill keep that in mind, thanks

Comment: @kaylum noted, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When do you think will EOF occur, if you are reading from stdin? You need either signal handling or a terminating character.